# Portable way to "unpoint" a pointer typedef?

Tags: c, typedef, typeof

This is unfortunately defined in some external library: cannot touch!

```
// library.h
typedef struct {
    long foo;
    char *bar;
   /* ... (long & complex stuff omitted) */
} *pointer_to_complex_struct_t;
```

Now **The Question**: how to declare an **`complex_struct_t`** variable?

- Ideal solution but not allowed! (cannot change external library):

  ```
  // library.h
    /* ... (long & complex stuff omitted) */
  } complex_struct_t, *pointer_to_complex_struct_t;


  // my.h
  extern complex_struct_t my_variable;
  ```
- Non-portable solution (gcc):

  ```
  // my.h
  extern typeof( * (type_placeholder)0 )  my_variable; // Thanks caf!
  ```
- Other? Better? Thanks!

Bonus question: same question for a function pointer (in case there is any difference; I doubt it).

---

ADDED bonus: below is the exact same question but with functions instead of structs. This should not make any difference to the short answer ("No."), the only answer I was initially interested in. I did not expect some people to die trying to know and get my job done with creative workarounds, which is why I simplified the question from functions to structs (function pointers have special implicit conversion rules for convenience *and* confusion). But hey, why not? Let's get the copy-paste workaround competition started. Some workarounds are probably better than others.

```
///// library.h //////
// Signature has been simplified
typedef double (*ptr_to_callback_t)(long, int, char *);
// Too bad this is not provided: typedef double callback_t(long, int, char *);

///// my.h /////
// This avoids copy-paste but is not portable
typedef typeof( * (ptr_to_callback_t)0 ) callback_t;

extern callback_t callback_1;
extern callback_t callback_2;
extern callback_t callback_3;
// etc.
```

---

Short answer = no, there is currently no portable alternative to `typeof`

A basic copy-paste workaround works OK for *functions* but not for *structs*. The compiler will match the duplicated *function types*, but will not relate the duplicated *struct types*: a cast is required and the duplicated struct types will diverge without compilation warning.

Comment: They'll have done this precisely because they don't want you declaring such variables, surely. There may for example be no way to initialize the struct, which is guaranteed to work for past and/or future versions of the library, but they've given you the members so that you can read them or some such. So, since you're messing with the library's constraints, why not mess with the library header (not the library itself, just the header you include in your code)?

Comment: Sorry I mislead you: my real example is actually with functions, not structs. I simplified it to a struct because I wanted to avoid the whole "function == function pointer" mess at all costs. By the way this mess is probably what confused the "library" author into this unfortunate typedef - please do not overestimate this (actually internal) "library" :-)

Comment: @mu & others: this question was about the (lack of) capabilities of the C language from a theoretical, standard perspective. It was not about getting the job done. Only now I realize there might be some value in comparing the different copy-paste workarounds with each other.

Comment: You can improve the GCC dialect version to a single line: `typeof(*(pointer_to_complex_t)0) my_variable;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot do it with standard C. With C++ a simple metafunction would do the trick though.

However you could just copy-paste the definition of the struct thus leaving the original untouched

```
typedef struct {
 ///same  struct
} complex_struct_t;
```

The downside of this solution is that the expression `&complex_struct_t` won't be of type `pointer_to_complex_struct_t`, instead it will be of type pointer to unnamed `struct {//your members}`; 
You'll need reinterpret_casting, if you need that feature...

Comment: I hate copy-paste generally speaking for obvious reasons. But maybe in my (function typedef) case any divergence would be detected early at compile-time; I will try to make sure of that. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcH: The sad thing about this "solution" is that `&complex_struct_t` won't be of type `pointer_to_complex_struct_t`

Comment: & @secure: interesting. I realize I underestimated the differences between functions and structs.

Comment: @MarcH: Structs and functions are totally different -- the former contains data which is read and written, the latter is called and executed. Maybe if you write what you want to achieve could help, because by the inherent differences, `complex_struct_t my_variable;` is hard to translate to functions. And have you already tried it yourself? What did the compiler say?

Answer (score 1):

As written, the answer to your question is "no"; if all you have is a type definition of

```
typedef struct {...} *ptr_to_struct;
```

then there's no (standard, portable) way to extract the struct type.  If you have to create an instance of the struct, the best you will be able to do is

```
ptr_to_struct s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

and then refer to the fields in the struct using the `->` component selection operator (or by dereferencing `s` and using the `.` operator, but you don't want to do that).

You asked if the same thing applied to function pointers; you really need to state exactly what you mean.  If you have a situation like

```
typedef struct {...} *ptr_to_struct;
ptr_to_struct foo() {...}
```

then the situation is exactly like the above; you don't have a way to declare a variable of that type.

Comment: I just added the function pointer variant of the question above. It is different and simpler than what you assume in the last half of your answer: I suggest your remove this last half.

Comment: @MarcH: Edited as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Make a local copy of the header file and include it instead of the original. Now you can do anything you want. If this library could change (update or anything else), you could write a little script to automate these steps and call it from your makefile whenever you compile. Just make sure to not blindly paste into the header, search for the specific line (`} *pointer_to_complex_struct_t;`) and throw an error if it is no longer found.

Maybe you have to be a bit careful with the search paths for includes if this header uses other headers of this library. Plus, with the order of includes if itself is included by other headers.

EDIT (for your real goal mentioned in a comment): You can't do this with function pointers. Just write the function you want with the signature of the typedef, and it will be compatible to the pointer and can be called by it.

Comment: Yes I can also simply ignore the typedef and duplicate the type everywhere including in my header file. I can see multiple copy-paste based workarounds for this problem but to be really honest if I found copy-paste satisfying I would have not come here.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
pointer_to_complex_struct_t newStruct ( void ) {
    pointer_to_complex_struct_t ptr = 
         (pointer_to_complex_struct_t) malloc ( sizeof (*pointer_to_complex_struct_t) );
    return ptr;
}
```

You'd have to reference your newly created struct through ptr-> but you could create new ones.

Of course, this may or may not work, depending on how the struct is actually used.  The example that comes to mind is: what if the struct ends with

```
char data[0];
```

and data is used to point into the memory following the structure.